# php cannot insert data in database with PDO

Tags: php, html, database, pdo, insert

hello guys i am new in php and i try to make a  login-register form with php backend.
i watched some youtube tutorials and learned about a function called PDO.
i used it but got an error : [there is a screenshot of the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdmGq.png)
I know that i connected successfully because i tested it.
The problem is by inserting the data.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
                include_once "connection.php";





                if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {

                    global $dbCon;
                    global $dbDisCon;

                    $username = $_POST['userName'];
                    $password = $_POST['passWord'];
                    $eMail = $_POST['eMail'];

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (username, eMail, password) VALUES (:username,:eMail, :password )";

                    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':eMail',$eMail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $lastinsertid = $dbCon->lastinsertid();
                    if($lastinsertid){
                        console_log("data inserted");
                    }
                    else{
                        "something went wrong";
                    }



                }
```

Comment: the line 80 is :                 $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);

Comment: Debug `var_dump($dbCon);` and check whether you are getting connection object or not before that line.

Comment: object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
thats the debug

Comment: Did you test that directly before line 80?

Comment: yes i did it under the insert line

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need to use `global` when you're already in the global namespace (not inside a function/method)

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to get that error message if you get that output from `var_dump()` right before. Are you sure this is the code that actually throws the error? What code have you removed (since in the posted code, that `prepare()` is on line 19, not 80)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but it says undefined variable

Comment: If that's the case, you need to show us some context for this code. Show us all the code in this file up to the code you've posted (including what you've removed) and the contents of your `connection.php`. There are things going on here that you're not showing us.